# Does Angular have lifecycle same as React lifecycle useEffect with dependency? And what is it and example?

Tags: reactjs, angular, lifecycle

I have trouble with angular lifecycle

For example, I want to do some actions when a specific state/property is changed

React code example:

```
const [isChanged, setIsChanged] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
     // do some actions I expect here
}, [isChanged]);
```

How to change the code above into Angular code.
Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular has the OnChanges interface, which provides the ngOnChanges lifecycle method.

Here's the example from the official documentation:

```
@Component({selector: 'my-cmp', template: `...`})
class MyComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() prop: number = 0;

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    // changes.prop contains the old and the new value...
  }
}
```

This is a catch-all for all property changes.

If you just want to do something when one particular property changes, it might be "cleaner" to just use a setter for the property, and invoke your desired behavior there, for example:

```
@Component({selector: 'my-cmp', template: `...`})
class MyComponent implements OnChanges {
  _prop: number = 0;
  @Input() set prop(value: number) {
    const oldValue = this._prop;
    this._prop = value;
    this.onPropChange(oldValue, this._prop);
  }

  get prop(): number {
    return this._prop;
  }

  onPropChange(oldValue: number, newValue: number) {
  }
}
```